# how to stop url appending in angular 2 application using core angular2 router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My application is getting appened inside another application and I cannot append anything in the url as parent application is restrict.

Is there a way I can stop appending in the url. I am able to do the same in angular2 alpha 34 build by `this.router.navigate(value, true);`

I want to do the same in @angular:2.0.1 and in the html not in my typescript class by defining a method and calling it on (click).

Comment: what does this mean `My application is getting appened inside another application`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `skipLocationChange`:

```
router.navigate(['team', 33, 'user', 11], {relativeTo: route, skipLocationChange: true });
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html

Comment: Is there a way I can do that from  my html?

Comment: Don't think so. `routerLink` doesn't seem to provide an option.

Comment: What relativeTo: route does? without that option its working for me now. also cleaned it up little bit

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the code from the linked docs page. You only need to pass the route if you use relative paths from child routes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is it possible to apply for overall app instead of adding to each navigation?

Comment: I don't think so, but didn't follow Angular progress for a while.

Answer (score 2):

skipLocationChange: true prevent angular2 to append anything in URL. As @Günter Zöchbauer suggested, You need to pass skipLocationChange: true as the default value is false.

full code will be:

```
import { Router }   from '@angular/router';

export class MovingInPages {

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    moveToAnotherPage(value: string) {
        this.router.navigate([value], { skipLocationChange: true });
    }
}
```

The html will be like below:

```
<button type="button"  (click)="moveToAnotherPage('another-page-route')" class="btn btn-primary">Another page</button>
```